# Android apps able to communicate without permissions set

Tags: android, permissions

I was under the impressions that two apps were sandboxed and unable to call each other (by intents or contentresolver etc) unless the callee declared and enforced specific permissions and the caller used  appropriate uses-permission elements? However, I have developed two apps, one containing a content provider, and another with activities that use the content provider. Neither have permissions declared enforced or used. I deploy them directly from Eclipse to my phone and they are able to use each other.

I have checked that they really are running as separate processes and user ids, and they are. Why am I not seeing security exceptions? Should Linux underneath, by default, stop this communication? They will be signed by the default DEBUG certificate. Does this give them more rights to "talk" to each other, i.e. if I signed with an explicit certificate would the sandboxing kick in?

As soon as I declare and enforce a permission in the content provider app the other app does need the uses-permission to allow communication.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if your apps have the same signature, then they have access to each other.  It's similar to package level permissions in java.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html

Comment: But that documentation states that every app has a separate user ID and that if you want to get two of your apps (with same signature) to be able to talk to each other then you use the sharedUserId attribute.

Comment: Actually, I think it says if you want them to share data, they have to have the same user Id.  When communicating via Intents or ContentProviders you're using IPC.  That is fine until you try to share data or resources.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that's what it must be. I don't think the documentation is really clear on this point though.

Comment: Definately not.  And it changes regularly.